# Laplace transforms for transient analysis

Tags: transient, laplace-transform

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWhSDk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For `t<0` the switch is opened.

At`t=0` the switch is closed. The problem asks for the behaviour 
 of `i(t)` after closing the switch. I tried to solve it with KVL but result is different from the book. The current `i(t)` for `t<0` is 1.73A. So I converted the above circuit to the Laplace domain.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn3xH9.png)</sup>

Then I applied KVL and I found a current and

[image]

Using the inverse Laplace the result is different from the one in the book wich is found using differential equations in the time domain. 
Can someone try to solve the circuit? Thanks

Comment: What solution does "the book" provide? What result do you get, expressed as a function of time?

Comment: How do you get the 17mV initial condition; it looks wrong? Probably better to do the analysis with the current source rather than convert to a voltage source.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson the result of the book is $$
I(s) = -63.6e^{-638.2t}+7.72e^{-861.8t}+17.27+19
$$

Comment: @ElliotAlderson mine is $$I(s) =4247.46e^{-638.2t}+4245.73e^{-861.8t}$$

Comment: @Chu I found it considering the inductor as a wire in stationary conditions and it is the same of my book. Which value do you think is correct?

Comment: But the initial condition is based on the inductance, not the resistance of the inductor! We assume ideal components unless otherwise stated; inductor resistance = 0. This is why it's easier to use the current source in this particular case - the initial condition is then 19/11 A through the inductor.

Comment: That's what I wrote $$19/11 \approx 1.73A$$ converting to the Laplace domain the voltage source is $$L\cdot i_0$$ where $$i_0$$ is the current on the inductor before closing the switch. Am I wrong?

Comment: Initial voltage is \$L\frac{di}{dt}\$, not \$L \: i_0\$

Comment: I don't chat...

Comment: I'm talking about the laplace domain [link] https://web.archive.org/web/20170329061634/https://www.ece.uvic.ca/~jbornema/ELEC300/300-09%20-%20Circuit%20Transforms-I.pdf  page 6

Comment: OK, i'll have another look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The voltage, \$\small V(s)\$ at the top node, for each branch, is given by:

$$\small V(s)= \frac{19}{s}\small -I_1(s)$$

$$\small V(s)=I(s)\left(\frac{s}{100}\small+10\right)-0.017$$

$$\small V(s)=\left((I_1(s)-I(s)\right)\frac{500}{s}$$

where \$\small I_1(s)\$ is the source current.

Solving simutaneously: \$\small I(s)=\large\frac{1.727}{s}+\frac{7.72}{s+861.8}-\frac{7.72}{s+638.2}\$

Giving the time function: \$\small I(t)=1.727+7.72e^{-861.8t}-7.72e^{-638.2t}\$.

By inspection of the diagram, \$\small I(t) =1.727 A\$ is the correct current for \$\small t=0 \$ and \$\small t=\infty\$.

Comment: Have you applied KVL after the convertion?

Comment: I've written three expressions for the voltage at the top node, then solved the three simultaneous equations. Note: The inductor current must be 1.727A at t=0 and at t=infinity. Are you writing the initial condition as 0.017/s? It should be just 0.017.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I have a last question. 
I imposed the initial condition with the voltage generator for the inductor but I can't figure out how to impose the condition for t=infinity. I mean how can the Laplace method takes in consideration the final condition, when I solve the same circuit with the differential equations I have to use the condition at t=infinity

Comment: There is no need to impose a condition at infinity, I only used this to verify the equations - see my updated answer.